# How to get the "Owner" (not the parent) of a class when it is aggregated as member of another class

Tags: c#

Aggregation is prefered to inheritance. In inheritance can know the parent. In Aggregation how can one know the Owner in C# ?

If I add an explicit reference to the parent that's evil since I would create a dependency in the other way whereas the compiler knows the parent for sure. Is there any way to hack using reflection or something else except creating this reference.

How Visual Studio can build the call stack if the owner wasn't known? Visual Studio knows all the links that wire instances so there should be a way to do what Visual Studio does ?

Comment: The compiler does not know the parent, and neither does the runtime.

Comment: For sure it does know since the child is wired as member of the parent.

Comment: You are wrong.  .Net does not work that way.  What if you put the same child in two parents?

Comment: Then you can get a collection what problem ?

Comment: No, you can't.  You cannot find out who references you.

Comment: How Visual Studio can build the call stack if the owner wasn't known? Visual Studio knows all the links that wire instances so there should be a way to do what Visual Studio does ?

Answer (score 6):

You can't, without adding code for it. Heck, one instance may be "contained" within several different objects:

```
IAuthenticator authenticator = new PasswordAuthenticator();
Foo foo = new Foo(authenticator);
Bar bar = new Bar(authenticator);
```

Assuming both `foo` and `bar` remember the authenticator, which of them is the "owner" of the single `PasswordAuthenticator` instance?

More importantly, why would do you need to know? If you're sure there's a really good design reason for the "child" object to know about the relationship, add appropriate code for it (possibly an event, if that's sensible based on what you need it for). But make sure it's really necessary first.

Comment: As I said if I want to replace inheritance by aggregation then I'll need to replace parent property by the owner property.

Comment: @user310291: You've claimed you need to, but without explaining *why* you need to. What are you trying to get at in the "owner"? Using composition instead of inheritance isn't usually just a case of switching from one to the other without considering the overall design.

Comment: I need to for the same reason that in inheritance you sometimes need the parent property since I told you I was thinking about substituing Inheritance with Aggregation and I realize that I would maybe encounter some troubles in the way like this.

Comment: @user310291: That sounds very much like you don't *know* that you need the parent, you just *think* you might. If you find you *do* need the "parent" then maybe inheritance would be a better option. It's hard to say without a concrete example. It's not like inheritance is now something to avoid in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, unless you add a reference to the owner as a member of the aggregated class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for a class to know what other class (or classes) is using it, not directly.

Any class may be used (in aggregate) by many others - how do you determine which of those is the owner?

In general, such information is not really useful either (you would end up with tightly coupled code, full of switch statements on owner types), so there is no general mechanism to obtain it.

Comment: Oh that's very sad for me :( :) any hope sure ?

Comment: @user310291 - What are you trying to achieve? There may be design solutions for that, but without an actual problem description, one can't be offered.

Comment: Nothing specific I was just thinking that as I said if I want to replace inheritance by aggregation then I'll need to replace parent property by the owner property.

Comment: @user310291 - Again, this is rather vague. If you have an actual problem when implementing aggregation, ask. There are design patterns that may be applicable. The advice is to **prefer** composition over inheritance, not completely **replace** it.

Comment: I am on concept level about design pattern precisely. Best Practice is to avoid inheritance, still one can encounter practical problems to transpose inheritance with aggregation so I wanna know how generically you transpose the parent property ?

Comment: @user310291 - You don't "generically you transpose the parent property". You make a decision on which one is appropriate for your design and go with that. And you do it on a case by case basis.

Comment: The logical design is inheritance, then on implementation you have the choice to use adhoc inheritance or aggregation. If you use aggregation you should know the equivalence of parent.